# What would cause mortar to have a patchy finish?

Tags: basement, mortar, masonry

I started a re-pointing project in my basement, but it was way more work than I had anticipated, so I haven't continued in about six months.  However, now that i'm looking at mortar I originally tucked, it appears to be patchy, as if some of the lime is bleeding to the surface.

[image: brick - field stone joint]
[image: above grade brick]
(the bright white color is from the previous person's attempt to fix the cracks with what I believe to be cement that was too hard.)

### What is actually happening? and why?  If it should be avoided, how can I do so?

Comment: Inconsistencies in water mix can cause variations. Most likely efflorescence. Try cleaning with muriatic acid as per label instructions.

Comment: @OrganicLawnDIY doh - just returned a bottle of that after my tiling job.  Should other acids for gout (I have a 1/2 bottle leftover of the DuPont stuff) work?

Comment: Not sure which DuPont product you have. Read the label and see. You can also try straight distilled white vinegar.

Comment: I think it may be due to the fact I was trying to keep the joints wet while tucking but it was really hard to do constantly as the stone really sucked up the moisture quickly.   Further, I might have forgot to turn off the dehumidifier during one round of tucking...